# best character set and collation for storing Tags, and URLs in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, url, utf-8, latin1

I'm retrieving photos info from Flickr into my site. 
For each photo, the URL, title, and tags are saved in MySQL database.

I read a lot about the most suited character set for such values and I found its mostly between using utf8 or latin1.

Some titles and tags include symbols like the copyright (or similar ones). 
Will I be OK with Latin1 character set?

Answer (score 2):

**Always** use utf-8, everywhere, in your database, text editor, html metas, charset headers....

This is the only advice I can give you.

Answer (score 2):

**Never** use utf-8 in your database **if** the stored text is 100% ascii. Bloating each character with utf-8 could imply a significant performance hit if the text is indexed.

Comment: "100% ascii" sounds like a guy will spend a few hours debugging "something" "somewhere" in your system at one point in the next few years...

Comment: Because of course, it was *supposed* to be 100% ascii

Comment: Please let me know when you find a URL that contains non-ascii characters. If a Standard says "only ascii allowed" then storing it as non-ascii is not so clever.

Comment: But the guy mentions titles too; unless I misunderstand the use case, anything can be stored in there

Comment: Really depends on how many rows you are gonna have. If you have 20 pages the performance impact will be irrelevant. One day you might have an URL or tag with a special character and if your whole application is based on Ascii... that might be bad.

Comment: I'm wondering what type `StackOverFlow` are using for their tags :)